# Microsoft word changing startup path location

Tags: microsoft-word, boot, path

in microsoft word you can change the path to the startup folder from within options. I would like to know where word stores this change.. i would guess its somewhere in the registry but couldnt see it.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Word 2007 and can set the "Default File Location" under Word Options -> Save.

I found the RegKey located:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Word\Options\DOC-PATH

Warning! Be very cautious working with the Registry!!!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this and is looking for the folder that is read at startup (i.e. the [startup folder](https://addbalance.com/word/startup.htm#PageStart)) then that value can be set in registry, in the extended string `startup-path` under:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\word\options
```